# android lollipop - calendar events location missing

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-calendar

using a Nexus 5 with Android 5:

I am setting a calendar event with subject,time,alarm,info and also location(city, street and street number)
when i set the event and open it in the calendar app, i can see the location i've set and i can open it using google maps.

after a few minutes(Sync?) when i open the event, all of the data is there except the location.

on other devices (lower api levels) the event is synced and the location is saved...

this is my code for pushing an event to the calendar:

```
public static long pushAppointmentsToCalender(Activity curActivity, String title, String addInfo, String place, int status, long startDate, int length, int reminderMinutesBefore) {
    String eventUriString = getCalendarEventsUri();
    ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

    eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1); // id We need to choose from our mobile for primary==>its 1
    eventValues.put("title", title);
    eventValues.put("description", addInfo);
    eventValues.put("eventLocation", place);
    long endDate = startDate + length;
    eventValues.put("dtstart", startDate);
    eventValues.put("dtend", endDate);
    eventValues.put("eventStatus", status); // This information is        
    eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
    eventValues.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    Uri eventUri = curActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
    if (reminderMinutesBefore != -1) {//Event: Reminder(with alert) Adding reminder to event 
        String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";
        ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

        reminderValues.put("event_id", eventID);
        reminderValues.put("minutes", reminderMinutesBefore); // Default value of the            
        reminderValues.put("method", 1); // Alert Methods: Default(0), Alert(1), Email(2), SMS(3)

        Uri reminderUri = curActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);
    }
    Logger.log("pushAppointmentsToCalender==>Event Created with eventId:" + eventID);
    return eventID;

}
```

Comment: Where did you get those "magic strings" for eventValue? API documentation uses constants for this (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event).

Comment: right here in the All-Mighty StackOverflow.... I'll try to change to constants....

Comment: changed the entire method to use Constants (My bad)
but still:
after a few second, when the device syncs the calendar event to the Google servers, it deleted the Location

Comment: apparantly, this happens in ICS also....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is an open bug in the new Sync mechanizm that Google created,  more info can be found here:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/calendar/location%7Csort:date/calendar/CgCWaYcraVQ/sDkpp76YWNkJ

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79840